# Can you create a microsoft bot FormFlow in vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, botframework

I've come across one issue following the tutorial at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-formflow in a vb.net project.

Specifically around "Connect the form to the framework" where the following code exists.

```
internal static IDialog<SandwichOrder> MakeRootDialog()
{
    return Chain.From(() => FormDialog.FromForm(SandwichOrder.BuildForm));
}
```

Which I have in my vb.net

```
Friend Shared Function MakeRootDialog() As IDialog(Of SandwichOrder)
    Return Chain.From(Function() FormDialog.FromForm(Of IForm(Of SandwichOrder))(SandwichOrder.BuildForm))
End Function
```

The error highlighted is that FromForm

> must have a public parameterless instance constructor to satisfy the 'New' constraint for type parameter 'T'.

Which makes sense to me, as it does, IForm clearly has.

> Protected Sub New()

I don't c# very often, but I can't figure out why it works there and doesn't return the same error especially since the constructor in c# is.

> protected IForm();

I'm thinking that I'm creating a new instance of the class where in c# we aren't.... But I can't figure out why that would be.

Does anybody have any clues?

**edit:**

While in c# the following does work

```
return Chain.From(() => FormDialog.FromForm(SandwichOrder.BuildForm));
```

The following does not, even though they are the same but with the correct type parameters.

```
        return Chain.From(() => FormDialog.FromForm<IForm<SandwichOrder>>(SandwichOrder.BuildForm));
```

The reason I wasn't using the equivalent vb

```
Return Chain.From(Function() FormDialog.FromForm(SandwichOrder.BuildForm))
```

Was that I get the following error.

> type parameter(s) in method cannot be inferred from these arguments. Specifying the data type(s) explicitly might correct this error.

And I followed the instructions, this apparently caused the error above and might be a red herring. Apparently, I have another problem to figure out, why in vb.net it thinks the return of the function isn't identical.

Buildform is wonderfully simple and is just.

```
Public Shared Function BuildForm() As IForm(Of SandwichOrder)
    Return New FormBuilder(Of SandwichOrder)().Message("Welcome to the simple sandwich order bot!").Build()
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

The issue was BuildFormDeligate - the expected type for FromForm was not been implicitly returned. The solution was to simply create the object and pass it in. Odd since I didn't need to do this in c# but hey ho.

```
Dim BuildFormDeligate As New BuildFormDelegate(Of SandwichOrder)(AddressOf SandwichOrder.BuildForm)

Return Chain.From(Function() FormDialog.FromForm(BuildFormDeligate))
```